# java.util.ConcurrentModificationException while inserting in ArrayList

Tags: java, collections

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.ListIterator;

public class MyList {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();

        al.add("S1");
        al.add("S2");
        al.add("S3");
        al.add("S4");

        Iterator<String> lir = al.iterator();

        while (lir.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(lir.next());
        }

        al.add(2, "inserted");

        while (lir.hasNext()) {
           System.out.println(lir.next());
        }
    }
}
```

The particular piece of code throws an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(Unknown Source)
    at collections.MyList.main(MyList.java:32)
```

Comment: I bet I can find more than 10 duplicates in SO.

Answer (score 7):

It happens due to array list is modified after creation of `Iterator`.

> The iterators returned by this ArrayList's iterator and listIterator
>   methods are fail-fast: if the list is structurally modified at any
>   time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the
>   iterator's own remove or add methods, the iterator will throw a
>   ConcurrentModificationException. Thus, in the face of concurrent
>   modification, the iterator fails quickly and cleanly, rather than
>   risking arbitrary, non-deterministic behavior at an undetermined time
>   in the future.

[Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#iterator%28%29)

```
Iterator<String> lir = al.iterator(); // Iterator created

while (lir.hasNext()) 
    System.out.println(lir.next());
al.add(2, "inserted"); // List is modified here
while (lir.hasNext()) 
    System.out.println(lir.next());// Again it try to access list
```

What you should do here create new iterator object after modification.

```
...
al.add(2, "inserted");
lir = al.iterator();
while (lir.hasNext()) 
    System.out.println(lir.next());
```

Answer (score 3):

You are modifying the Collection and then trying to use the same iterator.

1. Get the Collection iterator again

   ```
   al.add(2, "inserted");
   Iterator<String> lirNew = al.iterator();
   while (lirNew.hasNext()) {
   System.out.println(lirNew.next());
   }
   ```
2. or Use [ListIterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html)

   ```
   ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();

   al.add("S1");
   al.add("S2");
   al.add("S3");
   al.add("S4");

   ListIterator<String> lir = al.listIterator();

   while (lir.hasNext()) {
       System.out.println(lir.next());

   }

   lir.add("insert");

   while (lir.hasNext()) {
       System.out.println(lir.next());

   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You add object to list, after the iterator is instanced. This will change the value of modCount in inner class AbstractList$Itr.class. next() method of iterator will call checkForComodification() method, which throws a ConcurrentModificationException. And this is so called fail-fast.

```
 //add in abstractList
 public void add(int index, E element) {
    if (index<0 || index>size)
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    checkForComodification();
    l.add(index+offset, element);
    expectedModCount = l.modCount;
    size++;
    modCount++;  //modCount changed
}
```

In AbstractList$Itr

```
int expectedModCount;

public E next() {
        checkForComodification(); // cause ConcurrentModificationException
    try {
    E next = get(cursor);
    lastRet = cursor++;
    return next;
    } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
    checkForComodification();
    throw new NoSuchElementException();
    }
}

 private void checkForComodification() {
    if (l.modCount != expectedModCount)  //modCount not equals to itr.expectedModCount
        throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
}
```

redo this code after your add:

```
al.add(2, "inserted");
lir = al.iterator();
```

Comment: yah but why does this happens when I have limited the scope of iterator to while loop

Comment: It is not caused by scope, but your add() invocation. You'd better to read the jdk source code.